# What are the sequence file format and parquet file formats in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive

Can you explain with a real time example where to use sequence file and parquet file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sequence Files**

*Sequence files store data in a binary format with a similar structure to CSV. Like CSV, sequence files do not store metadata with the data so the only schema evolution option is appending new fields. However, unlike CSV, sequence files do support block compression. Due to the complexity of reading sequence files, they are often only used for “in flight” data such as intermediate data storage used within a sequence of MapReduce jobs.*

**Parquet Files**

*Parquet Files are yet another columnar file format that originated from Hadoop creator Doug Cutting’s Trevni project. Like RC and ORC, Parquet enjoys compression and query performance benefits, and is generally slower to write than non-columnar file formats. However, unlike RC and ORC files Parquet serdes support limited schema evolution. In Parquet, new columns can be added at the end of the structure. At present, Hive and Impala are able to query newly added columns, but other tools in the ecosystem such as Hadoop Pig may face challenges. Parquet is supported by Cloudera and optimized for Cloudera Impala. Native Parquet support is rapidly being added for the rest of the Hadoop ecosystem.*

*One note on Parquet file support with Hive... It is very important that Parquet column names are lowercase. If your Parquet file contains mixed case column names, Hive will not be able to read the column and will return queries on the column with null values and not log any errors. Unlike Hive, Impala handles mixed case column names. A truly perplexing problem when you encounter i*